# How to customize a Debian system image without a Python environment?

Tags: debian, docker

I am a Docker beginner and I would like to customize my own container image using Debian's official container image. However, the container images provided by the official platform come with their own Python environment, which is Python 3.11 version and 64 bit. I do not want it to come with its own Python environment now, or how can I handle it so that it can come with 32-bit Python 3.8?

Dockerfile:

```
#FROM debian:latest
#FROM debian:bookworm
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
#FROM debian:11-slim
#FROM ubuntu:20.04-i386
# for 32bit
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python

RUN apt-get remove --purge python3 -y
#RUN apt-get install python3.8:i386 -y
RUN apt-get install net-tools \
        uml-utilities \
    bridge-utils\
    iputils-ping \
    vim \
    openssh-server \
    openssh-client \
    curl \
    gpg \
    psmisc \
    samba \
    samba-common \
    redis \
    unzip \
    file \
    libc-bin \
    dos2unix \
    mosquitto \
    -y

RUN apt-get install libc6:i386 -y
RUN apt-get install lib32stdc++6 -y
```

Comment: If you want `i386` architecture, have you thought about using the [`i386` Debian Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/debian/)?  If you need to use Python 3.8, you are limited to using Debian Bullseye.  If you do not want Python installed by default, use the `slim` images.